# How to bundle and minify javascript in continuous integration (jenkins)

Tags: javascript, jenkins, continuous-integration

I was looking for MsBuild tasks or command line tools to force web essentials javascript bundle generation and less compilation and did not find any.

Please help,
Pim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/).

Comment: Hi @yossiz74 thank you so much for reply. I am now looking more info for Yui Compressor. I have found that ==>  "The YUI Compressor is no longer maintained by Yahoo" (Aug 2014)  is this will be an issue of no supporting or any concern?

Comment: We, and many other people I know, are still using it today (April 2016) and have no concern. The functionality is quite basic at its core, so I doubt there is much need for maintenance.

Comment: Hi yossiz74, thank you very much for your reply. I will sure take a look more detail at YUI Compressor.Thank you.